# legal value for prime factorization

Tags: factoring

My understanding of mathematics is poor, although I'm trying to improve it, so I hope you will forgive me for asking a rather basic question.

I've written a computer code that prints the prime factors of a natural number. It works well. For instance, for the input $72$ it prints $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3$. On youtube I saw somebody calculate the input $-72$ to $-1 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3$, so I adjusted my code to accept all whole numbers. But now I'm wondering what to do if the input is $0$.

Should I simply return $0$ (or $1$)? Should I refuse the input?

I tried some online prime factor calculators to see what would happen, but they either ignored/refused input of non-natural numbers, or, in one case, crashed my browser :-)

Comment: This is the [*Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). Look at the prime factorization results from [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer+factors+%7B0%2C+1%2C+-1%2C+72%2C+-72%2C+1234567890%7D). Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positive integers have a prime factorization (i.e., can be written as a product of zero or more factors, all of which are prime numbers.)
You may already have a problem with the input $1$ as it does not have any prime factors (while writing $1 = 1$ just like $17=17$ might seem to imply that $1$ is prime).
Prepending a factor of $-1$ for negative input is already a trick, as $-1$ is not a prime either. (In the ring of integers, these two exceptions $1$ and $-1$ are the so-called *units*).
Technically, $0$ is a multiple of any prime, but it des not have a prime factorization. So before you start outputting $0 = 0\times 2\times 3\times 5$, I suggest you just output the non-factorization $0=0$ (as you would also output $-1=-1$ and $1=1$),

Comment: One could say that $1$ does not have any prime factors but _does_ have a prime factorization, but $0$ doesn't have a prime factorization.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I wanted to imply that - but even $1$ poses the "problem" to write down the empty product